# UITableViewCell capability to match design

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to get the following with `UITableViewCell` without creating custom `UITableViewCell`?

[image]

Comment: For this type of cell you need to make your own custom cell

Comment: One word: Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with out `custom cell`.

```
var tableView = UITableView()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myIdentifier")

    tableView.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y:64, width:self.view.bounds.width, height:self.view.bounds.height)//Optional for table size

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let myCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "myIdentifier")

    myCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 137/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0)
    myCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    myCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    myCell.textLabel?.halfTextColorChange(fullText: "Claim Submission\n6/10/2016", changeText: "6/10/2016")

    myCell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 137/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0)
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11) // (ofSize: 11)
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.halfTextColorChange(fullText: "$0.01\nBal:$999.99", changeText: "Bal:$999.99")


    return myCell
}


extension UILabel {
  func halfTextColorChange (fullText : String , changeText : String ) {
    let strNumber: NSString = fullText as NSString
    let range = (strNumber).range(of: changeText)
    let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: fullText)
    attribute.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.darkGray , range: range)
    attribute.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9)], range: range)
    self.attributedText = attribute
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to design everything in xib using *layouts*. Then you easily can implement quite complex design ideas, such as (example): 70% of cell has top and bottom parts, the final 30% is vertically centered and has right layout. Entire cell is always occupying the space available, etc. If you do thing right then you never have this headache again, you will not care anymore what device it runs on, etc. Why xib, you may ask? Because once designed cell can be used both in iphone and ipad with the same code.

That was about ui, now to the class. In described situation, your custom cell class will simply have data populating code and some logic if needed.